# Compare strings in two files

Tags: scripts, text-processing

I am trying to get the name of the user from one file and their corresponding details from my other file. I use awk:

```
awk -F : '{ print $1 }' user-name
```

it gives me the list of all the user's. So now how can I match these names with the other file and get a output like:

```
user-name id contact-details
```

The format of the two files is like follows:

1.user-name

```
Tarun:143
Rahul:148
Neeraj:149
```

2.user-details

```
Tarun:tarun@gmail.com
Neeraj:neeraj@xyz.com
Rahul:rahul@gmail.com
```

what I'm trying to get is like:

```
Neeraj:149:neeraj@xyz.com
Rahul:148:rahul@gmail.com
Tarun:143:tarun@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the join command

```
join -t ":" username contacts
```

username file has the format

```
user1:id1
user2:id2
```

contacts has the format

```
user1:contact1
user2:contact2
```

When the file is not sorted then you can do the following

```
sort -b username > username.sorted
sort -b contacts > contacts.sorted
```

and then run the join command on username.sorted and contacts.sorted

or as another [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/514179/156999) pointed out you can do it directly using

```
join -t ":" <(sort -b username) <(sort -b contacts)
```

Comment: this solution only work for `sorted list of users in both files `. but +1

Comment: what if the list is not sorted?

Comment: @Tarun If username file like `user1:id user2:id` and contacts file like `user2:details user1:details` after running, this command tell you `join: contacts:userNUM: is not sorted: user1:details`. if you save the output of running and `cat` it you will see only sorted user written in output. see the output of this (`join -t  ":" user-name details | tr ":" " " > out
`) then `cat out`

Comment: updated the answer to handle unsorted files

Comment: Now you removed all `:` between user-name and contacts! if you want true of that here it is (`join -t ':' user-name.sorted details.sorted | tr '' ':'`) but after sorted. please edit your answer with this correct.

Comment: If you run your code then you will see you have replaced all `:` with whitespace character.

Comment: Ah yeah, I thought that was in the initial requirement. He can get rid of the `tr` command if he wants it delimited by `:`

Comment: Ya I already did that.

Answer (score 4):

In a python script:

**A pragmatic solution**

In case it is a "one time job", specific for one situation, the following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open(file1) as names:
    names = sorted(names.readlines())
with open(file2) as data:
    data = data.readlines()
for i in names:
    item = i.replace("\n", "")+str([d[d.find(":"):].replace("\n", "") for d in data if d.startswith(i.split(":")[0])][0])
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
Neeraj:149:neeraj@xyz.com
Rahul:148:rahul@gmail.com
Tarun:143:tarun@gmail.com
```

Or, if you want to save the output directly into a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open(file1) as names:
    names = sorted(names.readlines())
with open(file2) as data:
    data = data.readlines()
with open(file3, "wt") as output:
    for i in names:
        output.write(i.replace("\n", "")+str([d[d.find(":"):].replace("\n", "") for d in data if d.startswith(i.split(":")[0])][0])+"\n")
```

As you probably know, copy the script into an empty file, set the path to the file 1-2 (3) (between quotes), save it as `combine.py`, run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/combine.py
```

**A more database-worthy solution**

Looking at the two files, we are actually dealing with databases, with the first field as a key. The following script is more flexible and covers a more flexible way of making reports of the two files, in situations (for example) where we would have more fields than here is the case.

If we would add an extra ("characterizing") field to the second file:

```
Neeraj:neeraj@xyz.com:Loves to Cook
Rahul:rahul@gmail.com:Collects empty bottles
Tarun:tarun@gmail.com:Weares his glasses upside down
```

We might want to add the characterization instead of the email address, or both. That would ask for a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

db1 = "/path/to/file1"; db2 = "/path/to/file2"

with open(db1) as data1:
    rc = [l.replace("\n", "").split(":") for l in data1.readlines()]

with open(db2) as data2:
    records2 = [l.replace("\n", "").split(":") for l in data2.readlines()]

uniques = sorted(set(item[0] for item in rc)) # find keys
report = []

for i in uniques:
    database_1 = [r for r in rc if r[0] == i][0]
    database_2 = [r for r in records2 if r[0] == i][0]
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # set the required fields for report here:
    new_record = i, database_1[1], database_2[1]
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    report.append((":").join(new_record))

for item in report:
    print(item)
```

*Result*

If we set:

```
new_record = i, database_1[1], database_2[2]
```

The result is:

```
Neeraj:149:Loves to Cook
Rahul:148:Collects empty bottles
Tarun:143:Weares his glasses upside down
```

But if we set:

```
new_record = i, database_1[1], database_2[1]
```

The result is:

```
Neeraj:149:neeraj@xyz.com
Rahul:148:rahul@gmail.com
Tarun:143:tarun@gmail.com
```

And if we set:

```
new_record = i, database_1[1], database_2[1], database_2[2]
```

The result is :

```
Neeraj:149:neeraj@xyz.com:Loves to Cook
Rahul:148:rahul@gmail.com:Collects empty bottles
Tarun:143:tarun@gmail.com:Weares his glasses upside down
```

Answer (score 3):

With **process substitution** in `bash`, we can make a very compact variant of the `join` solution even for **unsorted** input files:

`join -t: <(sort user-name) <(sort user-details)`

The output is just like the example output in the question:

```
Neeraj:149:neeraj@xyz.com
Rahul:148:rahul@gmail.com
Tarun:143:tarun@gmail.com
```

We are using the first field/column of both files here. To use use other columns, use the options `-1` and `-2` (or `-j` if it's the same field). To be more explicit, we could use `join -t: -j 1 ...` or `join -t: -1 1 -2 1 ...` above. (See also [`man join`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/join.1.html))

The parts of the form `<(command)` are replaced by a named pipe from which the output of the command can be read. That means for the `join` command that it gets two files with sorted input as arguments.

(See `man bash | less '+/Process Substitution'`)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=: 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}{print $1,a[$1],$2}' user-name user-details 
Tarun:143:tarun@gmail.com
Neeraj:149:neeraj@xyz.com
Rahul:148:rahul@gmail.com
```

#### Explanation

- `-F:` : sets the field separator to `:`.
- `-v OFS=:` : sets the output field separator (`OFS`) to `:` for pretty printing.
- `NR==FNR` : `NR` is the current line number and `FNR` is the line number of the current file. When parsing more than 2 files, `NR` will be equal to `FNR` only for the 1st file. `NR` is incremented for each line of input while `FNR` is reset each time a new file is read.
- `{a[$1]=$2; next}` : this creates an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) called `a` whose key is the first field and whose value is the second. Once that is done, we skip to the next line with `next`.
- `{print $1,a[$1],$2}` : print the 1st field of this line, the value stored in the `a` array for that field and then the second field. Because of the `next` explained above, this will only be executed when `NR` is not equal to `FNR`. In other words, it will only be run when the second file is being read.

Answer (score 1):

Try with my code:

First sort both `user-name` and `contacts` and write the output into one file named `user-name_contacts` with this:

```
sort user-name contacts > user-name_contacts
```

Next, run this command to join two files:

```
sed -i '/$/N ; s/\n\(.*\):/:/' user-name_contacts
```

*Output:*

```
 Neeraj:149:neeraj@xyz.com
 Rahul:148:rahul@gmail.com
 Tarun:143:tarun@gmail.com
```

Comment: Won't this break the order? It might not work if the list of contacts and usernames are not in order.

Comment: Nope, not working. Here is the output
    `$cat user-name`

    A:1

    B:2

    `$cat contacts`

    B:Test2

    A:Test1

    `$sed 's/\(.*\)://g' contacts > new-contacts`
    `$sort user-name new-contacts > user-name_contacts`
    `$sed -i '$!N;s/\n/:/g' user-name_contacts`
    `$cat user-name_contacts`
    A:1:B:2
    Test1:Test2

Wrong output.

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM I have updated my answer.